# Excluding rows and create rank

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerquery

I am trying to create a rank that only have ranking on rows that have certain values. I have created a column called "RankingTop" that ranks by ReportType and ReportDate. So there are 2 separate rankings. I am trying to create a rank only for rows that have isCurrent = "no". This is my code & dataset I have right now along with what I am trying to achieve. Please let me know if this is possible. Or could I do this in PowerQuery.

```
RankingTop = RANKX (
FILTER(
    Table,
    Table[ReportType]
        = EARLIER(Table[ReportType])
)
, Table[ReportDate]
,
, DESC
)
```

Current dataset

```
| ReportType | ReportDate | RankingTop | MonthYear | isCurrent |
|------------|------------|------------|-----------|-----------|
| Weekly     | 12/27/2021 | 1          | Dec-21    | no        |
| Weekly     | 12/20/2021 | 2          | Dec-21    | no        |
| Weekly     | 12/13/2021 | 3          | Dec-21    | no        |
| Weekly     | 12/6/2021  | 4          | Dec-21    | no        |
| Weekly     | 11/29/2021 | 5          | Nov-21    | no        |
| Weekly     | 11/22/2021 | 6          | Nov-21    | no        |
| Weekly     | 11/15/2021 | 7          | Nov-21    | no        |
| Weekly     | 11/8/2021  | 8          | Nov-21    | no        |
| Weekly     | 11/1/2021  | 9          | Nov-21    | no        |
| Monthly    | 7/1/2021   | 7          | Jul-21    | no        |
| Monthly    | 8/1/2021   | 6          | Aug-21    | no        |
| Monthly    | 9/1/2021   | 5          | Sep-21    | no        |
| Monthly    | 10/1/2021  | 4          | Oct-21    | no        |
| Monthly    | 11/1/2021  | 3          | Nov-21    | no        |
| Monthly    | 12/1/2021  | 2          | Dec-21    | no        |
| Monthly    | 1/1/2022   | 1          | Jan-22    | yes       |
```

What I am trying to achieve

```
| ReportType | ReportDate | RankingTop | MonthYear | isCurrent |
|------------|------------|------------|-----------|-----------|
| Weekly     | 12/27/2021 | 1          | Dec-21    | no        |
| Weekly     | 12/20/2021 | 2          | Dec-21    | no        |
| Weekly     | 12/13/2021 | 3          | Dec-21    | no        |
| Weekly     | 12/6/2021  | 4          | Dec-21    | no        |
| Weekly     | 11/29/2021 | 5          | Nov-21    | no        |
| Weekly     | 11/22/2021 | 6          | Nov-21    | no        |
| Weekly     | 11/15/2021 | 7          | Nov-21    | no        |
| Weekly     | 11/8/2021  | 8          | Nov-21    | no        |
| Weekly     | 11/1/2021  | 9          | Nov-21    | no        |
| Monthly    | 7/1/2021   | 6          | Jul-21    | no        |
| Monthly    | 8/1/2021   | 5          | Aug-21    | no        |
| Monthly    | 9/1/2021   | 4          | Sep-21    | no        |
| Monthly    | 10/1/2021  | 3          | Oct-21    | no        |
| Monthly    | 11/1/2021  | 2          | Nov-21    | no        |
| Monthly    | 12/1/2021  | 1          | Dec-21    | no        |
| Monthly    | 1/1/2022   |            | Jan-22    | yes       |
```

Comment: You could certainly do this easily enough in Power Query, but it seems more complicated than the DAX formula. If you prefer PQ, let me know and I'll post something.

Comment: @RonRosenfeld I would prefer anything in PQ if possible. Please let me know! Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can tweak your calculated column to return `BLANK` if `isCurrent = "yes"`, and to filter `isCurrent` as well as `ReportType`:

```
RankingTop = 
    IF ( 
        'Table'[isCurrent] = "yes",
        BLANK(),
        RANKX (
            FILTER(
                'Table',
                'Table'[ReportType] = EARLIER ( 'Table'[ReportType] ) && 
                'Table'[isCurrent] <> "yes"
            ), 
            'Table'[ReportDate],
            ,
            DESC
        )
    )
```

Answer (score 1):

In Power Query, one way to create a "Rank" is to sort your list, and then add an Index column.

If I understand your issue correctly, we need to:

- Group by ReportType
- for each Group *(I used a custom function for this, but you could include in the main code)*

  - Sort the table be date in descending order
  - Add an index column to that subtable
  - Create a second table using a Filtered table for the sorting/add index column
- Then Join the rank tables using the Date as key
- Finally re-sort back to the original order
- I also added the Month/Year column and arranged the order as you showed in your desired output table

Please read the comments in the M-Code for more details
In this case, I started with just the three columns:  `ReportType`, `ReportDate` and `isCurrent`

***Original Data***
[image]

***Custom function***
*Paste the code into a BlankQuery and rename it `fnRank`*

```
(t as table, col as text)=>
let 
    sortedTable = Table.Sort(t,{col, Order.Descending}),
    addRank = Table.AddIndexColumn(sortedTable,"Rank",1,1,Int64.Type)
in addRank
```

**M Code**

```
let
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table1"]}[Content],
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{
        {"ReportType", type text}, 
        {"ReportDate", type date}, 
        {"isCurrent", type text}
            }),

//add index to preserve original date order
    #"Added Index" = Table.AddIndexColumn(#"Changed Type", "Index", 0, 1, Int64.Type),

//group by ReportType, sort and add index column for the ranking
    #"Grouped Rows" = Table.Group(#"Added Index", {"ReportType"}, {
        {"rank", each fnRank(_,"ReportDate"), type table},

//filter with parameter isCurrent=No
        {"rank2", each fnRank(Table.SelectRows(_,each [isCurrent]="no"), "ReportDate"), type table}
        }),

//join the two tables with the regular and filtered rank
    #"Added Custom" = Table.AddColumn(#"Grouped Rows", "joinRanks", 
        each Table.NestedJoin([rank],"ReportDate",[rank2],"ReportDate","ranks",JoinKind.LeftOuter)),

//remove unneeded columns and expand the join
    #"Removed Columns" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Added Custom",{"rank", "rank2"}),
    #"Expanded joinRanks" = Table.ExpandTableColumn(#"Removed Columns", "joinRanks", 
        {"ReportDate", "isCurrent", "Index", "Rank", "ranks"}, {"ReportDate", "isCurrent", "Index", "RankingTop", "ranks"}),
    #"Changed Type1" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Expanded joinRanks",{
        {"ReportDate", type date}, {"isCurrent", type text}, {"Index", Int64.Type}, {"RankingTop", Int64.Type}}),

//add a column to extract the filtered rank
//then remove the table column
    #"Added Custom1" = Table.AddColumn(#"Changed Type1", "RankingTopNo", 
        each try Table.SelectColumns([ranks],"Rank")[Rank]{0} otherwise null, Int64.Type),
    #"Removed Columns1" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Added Custom1",{"ranks"}),

//Sort back to the original order using Index column
//then remove the Index Column
    #"Sorted Rows" = Table.Sort(#"Removed Columns1",{{"Index", Order.Ascending}}),
    #"Removed Columns2" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Sorted Rows",{"Index"}),

//add MonthYear column as text
    #"Added Custom2" = Table.AddColumn(#"Removed Columns2", "MonthYear", 
        each Date.ToText([ReportDate],"MMM-yy"), type text),
    #"Reordered Columns" = Table.ReorderColumns(#"Added Custom2",{"ReportType", "ReportDate", "RankingTop", "RankingTopNo", "MonthYear", "isCurrent"})
in
    #"Reordered Columns"
```

***Results***>
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Another Power Query option:

```
let
    Source = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Table.FromRows(Json.Document(Binary.Decompress(Binary.FromText("fdDBCoAgEATQf9mzoLtR6kd07iAehaDQQ138+6xugnPb4TEwbAi0pXSclRSxaLFajHALuVBUHRqAPAFchsZaPEIByDNAh4qdrSXf+4cWmAPmgbFBiNa8bx3jb9LOmi6K8QE=", BinaryEncoding.Base64), Compression.Deflate)), let _t = ((type nullable text) meta [Serialized.Text = true]) in type table [ReportType = _t, ReportDate = _t, isCurrent = _t]),{{"ReportDate", type date}}, "en-US"),
    #"Added Sort" = Table.AddIndexColumn(Source, "Original Sort", 1, 1, Int64.Type),
    #"Created Partitions" = Table.Group(#"Added Sort", {"ReportType", "isCurrent"}, {{"Data", each _, type table}}),
    fnRank = (MyTable as table) =>
    let
        #"Sorted Rows" = Table.Sort(MyTable,{{"ReportDate", Order.Descending}}),
        #"Added Index" = if #"Sorted Rows"[isCurrent]{0} = "no" then Table.AddIndexColumn(#"Sorted Rows", "Rank", 1, 1, Int64.Type) else #"Sorted Rows"
    in
        #"Added Index",
    #"Augmented Partitions" = Table.AddColumn(#"Created Partitions", "RankedData", each fnRank([Data]), type table),
    #"Combined Partitions" = Table.Combine(#"Augmented Partitions"[RankedData]),
    #"Sorted Rows" = Table.Sort(#"Combined Partitions",{{"Original Sort", Order.Ascending}}),
    #"Removed Columns" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Sorted Rows",{"Original Sort"})
in
    #"Removed Columns"
```

Input:

[image]

Output:

[image]